# When we use Iframe to load another website what happen to data usage?

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

I am developing website by using ASP.net

In there I have a page where I use a iframe to load another website inside my website. Lets say I am opening WWE.com, Youtube.com inside the iframe. When we normally surf these websites it will take while to load these.

So when I do that will the bandwidth will be serve from my website/Server? or theirs?

Comment: Their bandwidth will be used, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using iframe, the clients bandwidth will be consumed.